# How dagger works for multiple modules in an Application?

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have an application which has so many modules. Now I want to know if dagger will inject dependencies for all modules separately when each module is launched or it will inject all modules at once when application is launched ?

Answer (score 0):

When the application runs, `Dagger` only init object when your `Model` request `dependencies object`. Base on you defined `Scope` Dagger will decide `reuse` or `create a new object`.